# PDF Output varies by browser

Tags: php, apache, pdf, gzip, tcpdf

I am outputting a PDF using TCPDF (the newest version), and I'm running into an issue where some users are getting PDFs that appear to be broken.  It's always the same people, so it's related to their browser I'm assuming, and they are getting the issue on a variety of browsers (Firefox and Chrome included).  I have already disabled GZIP in the HTTPD.CONF file, and when I check the Response Header on my browser (FireFox or Chrome) the transfer is binary encoding and has the proper content type.

Any thoughts? Is it possible that it is still being compressed for some reason?

++ By broken I mean that the file's text is off.  It doesn't use the font specified (looks like Arial and much larger than normal), and it enters blank pages somewhat randomly throughout the document.  The file is typically only 2 pages, and most of them are popping out with 6 to 7 pages.  I'm starting to wonder if it's a font issue, but when they email me the file, it appears broken on my machine as well.

+++ Also, I was able to get the response header from one of the guys who was having the issue, and it all appears to be transmitting correctly.  Using binary transfer and content type set correctly.

++++ The connection is SSL, so Wireshark does nothing for me, so short of hashing before outputting the file, is there a method for checking if the transfer is the issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "_some users are getting PDFs that appear to be broken_"? Do they get different file, or just their PDF reader displays it differently? If the file is the same, the only issue is with the rendering. Save the "_incorrect_" file and then try to open it on the machine that gets "_correct_" files.

Comment: Save the PDF to disk and send your user the data from the disk file. Then you will have the file as it should have been sent, and the file as they will have received it.

Answer (score 0):

o_0 Problem was related to the size of the font set within SugarCRM, and was specific to the user profile.  Not sure why changing the font 3pts caused 5 extra pages, but that resolved the issue.